# Parse a String Expression into Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a string for example `32,21C2L5N8C` stored in one field. Now I want to expand this string into as follows:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCLLNNNNNCCCCCCCC
```

After getting the above string, I want to count number of commas,C's,L's and N's.

Can some one help me with this please?

Comment: Is this for Microsoft SQL server, or for MySQL? Please delete the tag for the system you're not using.

Comment: I have got both the systems running at the moment. My priority is to get answer in SQL Server but MYSQL will also be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can extract the *numbers* and *none numeric characters* then then replicate each character, in *SQL Server* you can use [patindex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and [replicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) functions (explanations are in code):

```
--table variable for holding extracted numbers and none number characters
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), num int, nonnum char(1))

declare @str1 varchar(50)='32,21C2L5N8C' -- your current given string
declare @int1 varchar(50)='' --for number
declare @str2 varchar(50)='' --for none numeric characters
declare @result varchar(max)=''

while len(@str1)>1 --for parsing the given string
begin
    while (Select PatIndex('%[0-9]%', @str1))=1 --extract number
    begin 
        set @int1=@int1+substring(@str1,1,1)
        set @str1=substring(@str1,2,len(@str1)-1)
    end
    set @str2=substring(@str1,1,1) --extract none numeric character
    set @str1=substring(@str1,2,len(@str1)-1)
    insert into @t(num,nonnum)values (@int1,@str2)
    set @int1=''
    set @str2=''
end

select @result=@result+replicate(nonnum,num) from @t
select @result
```

**Output:**

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCLLNNNNNCCCCCCCC
```

**Edit 1:** if you have characters with no number in front of it inside the given string and you want to print it once you can add an extra `while` loop  in above code:

```
--table variable for holding extracted numbers and none number characters
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), num int, nonnum char(1))

declare @str1 varchar(50)='32,21C2L5NC' -- your current given string
declare @int1 varchar(50)='' --for number
declare @str2 varchar(50)='' --for none numeric characters
declare @result varchar(max)=''

while len(@str1)>1 --for parsing the given string
begin
    while (Select PatIndex('%[0-9]%', @str1))=1 --extract number
    begin 
        set @int1=@int1+substring(@str1,1,1)
        set @str1=substring(@str1,2,len(@str1)-1)
    end
    set @str2=substring(@str1,1,1) --extract none numeric character
    set @str1=substring(@str1,2,len(@str1)-1)
    insert into @t(num,nonnum)values (@int1,@str2)
    set @int1=''
    set @str2=''
    while (isnumeric(substring(@str1,1,1))=0 and len(@str1)>=1)
    begin
        set @str2=substring(@str1,1,1) --extract none numeric character
        set @str1=substring(@str1,2,len(@str1)-1)
        insert into @t(num,nonnum)values (1,@str2)
        set @int1=''
        set @str2=''
    end
end
select @result=@result+replicate(nonnum,num) from @t
select @result
```

*Output:*

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCLLNNNNNC
```

**Edit 2:** if you want the number of repeats of each character, just query the `@t` table variable in above code, I mean at the end of above query say:

```
select nonnum [char],num [repeat] from @t
```

*Output:*

```
char    repeat
,       32
C       21
L       2
N       5
C       1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by using a Pattern Splitter. Here is one taken from Dwain Camp's [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/). The function used, `PatternSplitCM`, is created by Chris Morris.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PatternSplitCM]
(
       @List                VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
       ,@Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 

RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
        n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
    (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
    (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
    (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
    (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n))

    SELECT
        ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
        [Matched]
    FROM (
        SELECT n, y.[Matched], Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.[Matched],n)
        FROM numbers
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT [Matched] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) y
    ) d
    GROUP BY [Matched], Grouper
```

Using the function above, you would want to split your string using the pattern `'[^0-9]'`, which means not numeric. You would then pivot the result so that the corresponding `number` and `character` will be on the same row. After that, you use `REPLICATE` to generate the strings and concatenate them at then end.

Your final query is:

```
DECLARE 
    @String     VARCHAR(8000),
    @Pattern    VARCHAR(50),
    @Result     VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @String     = '32,21C2L5N8C',
    @Pattern    = '[^0-9]',
    @Result     = ''


;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT  
        ID = (s.ItemNumber + 1)/ 2,
        Number = MAX(CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber % 2 = 1 THEN s.Item END),
        Character = MAX(CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber % 2 = 0 THEN s.Item END)
    FROM dbo.[PatternSplitCM](@String, @Pattern) s
    GROUP BY (s.ItemNumber + 1)/ 2
)
SELECT @Result = @Result + REPLICATE(Character, Number) FROM Cte ORDER BY ID

SELECT @Result
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c3f2/2/0)

---

Here is the step by step explanation:

First, split the given string using the pattern `'[^0-9]'`.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[PatternSplitCM](@String, @Pattern) s
```

The result is:

```
ItemNumber           Item       Matched
-------------------- ---------- -----------
1                    32         0
2                    ,          1
3                    21         0
4                    C          1
5                    2          0
6                    L          1
7                    5          0
8                    N          1
9                    8          0
10                   C          1
```

Second, pivot the result so that the corresponding number and character will be on the same row:

```
SELECT  
    ID = (s.ItemNumber + 1)/ 2,
    Number = MAX(CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber % 2 = 1 THEN s.Item END),
    Character = MAX(CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber % 2 = 0 THEN s.Item END)
FROM dbo.[PatternSplitCM](@String, @Pattern) s
GROUP BY (s.ItemNumber + 1)/ 2
```

The result is:

```
ID     Number     Character
------ ---------- ----------
1      32         ,
2      21         C
3      2          L
4      5          N
5      8          C
```

Last, use `REPLICATE(Number, Character)` to generate each string and concatenate them to get the final result:

```
SELECT @Result = @Result + REPLICATE(Character, Number) FROM Cte ORDER BY ID
SELECT @Result
```

The result is:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCLLNNNNNCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: Hey thats awesome .Thanks for that.Only one problem. If I don't have a number infront of the character this code doesnt work. My bad. I should have explained 2nd scenario. E.g. 32,21C2L5NC   There is no number infront of C so it should take 1 as default.

Comment: Does it mean that all of the characters are of length `1`?

Comment: For E.g. 32,21C2L5NC There is no number in-front of C so it should take 1 as default for C so the output string will be ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCLLNNNNNC

Comment: I suggest formatting first the input string to insert `1`.